# What side of the Typar paper faces the concrete when attaching to the back of the stud wall in my basement?

Tags: walls, insulation, basement

We are finishing our basement and live in Utah 5 climate zone. We already had the walls framed and now I'm seeing we should have placed the foam board first.  Now that the walls are up I'm looking at the next best option for proper insulation. We really don't have any water issues but the majority of the concrete wall is under ground.  I found that stapling Typar paper to the back side of the studs would supply a good air barrier and allow for air flow, then place the insulation in the wall.  My question is I found 2 different articles that conflict on which side of the paper should face the concrete. I am also leaning toward mineral wool instead of fiberglass insulation due to the density and if we did have any water it would hold up better.  We are also leaving our floor joists exposed and painting it flat black so I was reading that the mineral wool might be better for acoustics.  Any input would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that, if you asked the manufacturer, they'd say "install logo-side out", but only for possible publicity rather than any functional difference. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: This is left as a comment since it is an unscientific opinion. Typar and Tyvek are permeable, meaning they allow water vapor to pass through to keep condensation from building up. If it passes through one way, it will go through the other way. Since their brand name is on the side that automatically allows it to roll out for easy installation, that is the way it is typically done. again it should not matter.